# ROS Answers SE migration: 2D Mapping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way (or any example) to build a 2D map using Senz3D camera without using SLAM?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196556/2d-mapping/) by [Ragheb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20678/ragheb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this driver - https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic - to get a pointcloud from the camera. I'm not sure why it's not released as a ROS package, perhaps there are still issues to work out.

Sure, you can convert a single pointcloud into a flat 2D map. However without SLAM you will not be able to properly stitch multiple clouds together to obtain a combined map, so you will be limited by the sensor's FOV and occlusion.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0